# Is it possible to determine how many messages are in a POSIX message queue?

Tags: c++, queue, posix, message-queue, rhel

I am working with POSIX running on a RHEL machine. Is there a way to check the number of messages that are remaining in a message queue (System V Preferably)?

The purpose of this is simply a desire to know which queues have the most messages at a given time so that I can make a "managing" thread receive the messages in a Longest-Queue-First manner.

I didn't see anything about this in the man pages (that were C/C++-specific and not tied to IPCs).

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: How are you creating the message queues to begin with?

Comment: msgget(KEY, 0666 | IPC_CREAT) is what I'm currently using.

Comment: If you're using `msgget`, then you're not using POSIX message queues, but rather System V ones. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in comments that you are using [`msgget()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html) to create the message queue. In that case, you can use [`msgctl()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgctl.2.html) to get the number of messages in the queue, via the returned `msqid_ds::msg_qnum`  struct field.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, Thanks!